# React native TextInput border not working

Tags: android, react-native

Here's my style for the input:

```
 searchBarInput: {
  flex: 1,
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  color: 'white',
  height: 50,
  padding: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderColor: '#000000', 
  borderWidth: 50,  
  borderStyle: 'solid',
 }
```

If I change the border width, the size of the input changes, but still there's no visible border.

I am using react-native 0.15.0 with an android device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this answer your question : 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/docs/KnownIssues.md#text-input-border

It seems it is a known bug from react-native...

You can try and wrap it in a view component and set the border you want on the view component.

Comment: I think you can't change the border, that's the issue. you can just "make it invisible"...

Comment: Oh, I see. Then perhaps it's best wrapping it in another element?

Comment: Yes you should try and put it in a view and set the input flex: 1 then the border on the view.

Comment: I get 'underlineColor is not a valid style property' when I try to remove it. Edit: But it seems that setting backgroundColor: transparent does the trick. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

As per react native doc, you need to set below in text input properties:

```
multiline={true}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed on Android via `underlineColorAndroid="transparent"`

source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#text-input-border ([archive](https://archive.fo/ZUZd7))