# React-Native full box around text-input

Tags: react-native

The default component for TextInput creates a box that goes around the bottom and up the sides, how do I change it to make it go all the way around the text field?

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood your question properly, but this will give you a textinput with a gray 1px line around

```
<TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} value={this.state.text} />
```

Comment: I tried that but I cannot see the top of the border on my android device?

Comment: can you duplicate it on rnplay.org so I can see?

Comment: I think it is a known issue, I just found this so I think that answers my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984088/react-native-textinput-border-not-working